# Windows CMD - field separator

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to know that if there is any command in Windows command prompt that will do the following:

a. Read a file
b. Separates the field using delimiter and 
c. Print certain fields to the output.

I use AWK command for Ubuntu, but I don't know how to do it in Windows CMD.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic command is

```
for /f "tokens=...delims=..." %%a in (filename) do (...
```

You can get cocumentation by entering

for /?

at the prompt, or look at many, many posts in the `cmd` tag on SO for examples.

Comment: Thank You for your response. Can you please tell me where I made mistake on this command `FOR /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a IN (perf_final_24_to_42.txt) DO ECHO %%a` . The result is `%%a was unexpected at this time`

Comment: If you are running directly from the prompt, then you use `%a` in place of `%%a`. Better to put the command into a file called *whatever*.bat then just run *whatever* - that way, you don't have to keep retyping and the inevitable tyops. Your command should look for the first "word" on each line in the file - up to but not including the first space (if any), and ignoring any leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks again, your idea was successful. Also, I am trying to use `delims=$'\t'` to use tab as delimiter, it's not working. Do you know how to use tab, I tried `'\t'` , 4 spaces, `%TAB%`.

Comment: You need to use an actual TAB character, that is there would be exactly one character between the `=` and `"`, and that is a TAB.